# How to unify c and GHC.Exts.Item t c?

Tags: haskell, ghc

I just updated my [dynamic time warping library](https://github.com/fhaust/dtw/tree/ghc-7.10) to compile with `ghc-7.10` and stumbled into a strange problem:

The code that compiled fine in `ghc-7.8`:

```haskell
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedLists #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
dtwNaive :: (Ord c, Fractional c, DataSet a, DataSet b)
         => (Item a -> Item b -> c) -> a -> b -> c
dtwNaive δ as bs = go (len as - 1) (len bs - 1)
    where go 0 0 = 0
          go _ 0 = 1/0
          go 0 _ = 1/0
          go x y = δ (ix as x) (ix bs y) + minimum [ go (x-1)  y
                                                   , go  x    (y-1)
                                                   , go (x-1) (y-1)
                                                   ]
```

Now produces the following error:

```
src/Data/DTW.hs:112:52:
    Couldn't match type ‘c’ with ‘GHC.Exts.Item (t1 c)’
      ‘c’ is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for
            dtwNaive :: (Ord c, Fractional c, DataSet a, DataSet b) =>
                        (Item a -> Item b -> c) -> a -> b -> c
          at src/Data/DTW.hs:106:13
    Expected type: Int -> [c] -> t1 c
      Actual type: Int -> [GHC.Exts.Item (t1 c)] -> t1 c
    Relevant bindings include
      go :: Int -> Int -> c (bound at src/Data/DTW.hs:109:11)
      δ :: Item a -> Item b -> c (bound at src/Data/DTW.hs:108:10)
      dtwNaive :: (Item a -> Item b -> c) -> a -> b -> c
        (bound at src/Data/DTW.hs:108:1)
    In the first argument of ‘minimum’, namely
      ‘[go (x - 1) y, go x (y - 1), go (x - 1) (y - 1)]’
    In the second argument of ‘(+)’, namely
      ‘minimum [go (x - 1) y, go x (y - 1), go (x - 1) (y - 1)]’
    In the expression:
      δ (ix as x) (ix bs y)
      + minimum [go (x - 1) y, go x (y - 1), go (x - 1) (y - 1)]
```

I am honestly confused as I believe `[c]` to be the same thing as `[GHC.Exts.Item (t c)]` when `t ~ []`. What am I missing?

Comment: This looks like a bug. Is there any reason to have `OverloadedLists` enabled in this module?

Comment: No not really. Guess I needed it at some point. But removing it fixes the problem.

Comment: `OverloadedLists` is pretty much unusable with the Foldable changes in 7.10, though hardly anyone was using it anyways (5 modules in all of Hackage according to this recent survey: http://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/31t2y9/distribution_of_ghc_extensions_on_hackage/)

Comment: @ReidBarton that's sad. I actually use it quite a lot to define static vectors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of `minimum` is not the same as before. The old type was `Ord a => [a] -> a`. The new type is `(Ord a, Foldable t) => t a -> a`.

It's not obvious anymore that there is an `IsList` instance for the list literal that is the argument to `minimum`. You can fix the problem here by adding a local annotation:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
dtwNaive :: 
            forall a b c.
            (Ord c, Fractional c, DataSet a, DataSet b)
         => (Item a -> Item b -> c) -> a -> b -> c
dtwNaive = ...
    minimum ([go (x-1) y, go x (y-1), go (x-1) (y-1)] :: [c])
```

Comment: This doesn't fix the problem.  `Expected type: Int -> [c] -> [c1] Actual type: Int -> [GHC.Exts.Item [c1]] -> [c1]`. It seems that ghc now knows that this is a list, but not the relation between the list item (`c1`) and the actual type (`c`).

Comment: Could you provide a  type-checkable example? I filled in some guesswork code for `DataSet` and [it worked for me](http://lpaste.net/130347), but that's apparently not enough.

Comment: It's right there: https://github.com/fhaust/dtw/tree/ghc-7.10 (it's the fixed version as proposed by @Cirdec above).

Comment: Here's [DTW.hs](http://lpaste.net/130349) with my proposed fix. It works on GHC 7.10.1.

Comment: I think what I was missing was the existential quantification over `dtwNaive`.  I'll mark this as solved, but have used the easier way to just remove the `OverloadedLists` pragma.